# Code First: enable-migrations throws FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, console-application, entity-framework-migrations

I'm new to Entity Framework and wanted to try out a simple code-first project.

Using VS Community 2019 and SQL Server 2019 Developer. EF6 is installed for this console app (.NET Framework 4.8).

I got the following error when running enable-migrations in the Package Manager Console:

```
PM> enable-migrations
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\MyName\Source\Repos\CodeFirstDemo\Migrations'.
File name: 'C:\Users\MyName\Source\Repos\CodeFirstDemo\Migrations'
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.Data.Entity.Tools.Commands.ProjectCommandBase.WriteMigration(ScaffoldedMigration scaffoldedMigration, Boolean rescaffolding, Boolean force, String name)
   at System.Data.Entity.Tools.Commands.MigrationsEnableCommand.Execute()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at System.Data.Entity.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
Could not find file 'C:\Users\MyName\Source\Repos\CodeFirstDemo\Migrations'.
```

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8"/>
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BlogDbContext" connectionString="data source=DESKTOP-I42Q9CK;initial catalog=CodeFirstDemo;integrated security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Program.cs:

```
    using System;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace CodeFirstDemo
{
    // Entity Type
    public class Post
    {
        public int PostID { get; set; }
        public DateTime DatePublished { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }

    // DbContext
    public class BlogDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public BlogDbContext() : base("BlogDbContext")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var context = new BlogDbContext())
            {
                var post = new Post()
                {
                    DatePublished = DateTime.Now,
                    Title = "My Title",
                    Body = "My Post Body"
                };

                context.Posts.Add(post);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I believe the FileNotFoundException is a red herring. The line "Checking if the context targets an existing database..." takes a while and the path should have been created by the enable-migrations command.

If I run VS as administrator I get the same result.

However, if I skip the enable-migrations command and simply run the application the database is successfully created, but of course, no Migrations directory is created in the project directory.

Anybody knows what this is about and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

After I de-installed SQL Server 2019 Developer and installed SQL Server Express I could run the following commands successfully:

```
PM> enable-migrations
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
Code First Migrations enabled for project CF_NewDB.
PM> add-migration InitialModel
Scaffolding migration 'InitialModel'.
The Designer Code for this migration file includes a snapshot of your current Code First model. This snapshot is used to calculate the changes to your model when you scaffold the next migration. If you make additional changes to your model that you want to include in this migration, then you can re-scaffold it by running 'Add-Migration InitialModel' again.
PM> update-database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Applying explicit migrations: [202109290938475_InitialModel].
Applying explicit migration: 202109290938475_InitialModel.
Running Seed method.
```

I don't know why this didn't work with the Developer edition but at least for now I can continue with learning Code First.